# How do you find the average velocity of a damping spring mass system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, drag, oscillators

I did some research and found out that it can be assumed that:

> $\mathrm{Average \ Velocity} = 0.5 \ × \ V_{max} = 0.5 × \mathrm{angular \  frequency} \times\mathrm{maximum \ displacement}$

But which maximum displacement value should I use since the spring-mass system is damping?

Or is there a totally different way to find the average velocity?

Comment: Where did you find "it can be assumed that: Average Velocity = 0.5 * Vmax = 0.5 * angular frequency * maximum displacement" as it is not correct?

Comment: Someone on StackExchange mentioned that... check the first answer for this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652441/is-the-drag-coefficient-the-same-thing-as-damping-coefficient-can-i-find-the-dr/652478?noredirect=1#comment1465700_652478

Comment: He mentions that at the end of his answere

Comment: The average velocity over a given period of time is the total displacement in this time divided by the time. On the other hand, the average speed is the total distance moved divided by the time, and these are not the same.